# Redirect user using ip to different websites

Tags: php, ip, redirect

I am working with redirection by using ip.
Earlier it was working but now its not working .
I tried stack overflow solution but then too its not working.
If user is from india then redirect to another website and if from someone else then too another.
Help me get out of this.
Here is my code .

```
<?php

function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".getRealIpAddr());
echo $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;



?>
<?php 

$country = $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;


echo  $country;

if($country == "India")
{

header("Location: http://akreations.in/");


}
else
{
header("Location: https://www.anjkreations.com/");
}
?>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or what the problem is that you are having. What value is shown when you echo the country?

Comment: its showing united states

Comment: user from india should redirect to akreations and from rest of the world to anjkreations.com

Comment: Being in India does not necessarily mean that the IP that is being used is also from India. If the country being returned say United States I would guess that they are using a proxy that is based somewhere in the US. What is the value of `$ip` when the country shows as being US?

Comment: even if i am trying from indian ip then also showing same country

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party service and perform to remote lookup. This is the simpler option, as it requires no setup.

```
<?php
function getIP(){
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } 
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } 
else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
return $ip;
}

$ipaddress = getIP();

 function ip_details($ip) {
$json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/geo");
$details = json_decode($json, true);
return $details;
 }

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
$country= $details['country'];
if($country == "IN")
 {

 header("Location: http://akreations.in/");


}
else
{
header("Location: https://www.anjkreations.com/");
}
?>
```